# hash symbol is displayed in file in java

Tags: java, file, fileoutputstream

```
 File f = new File("even.txt");
 FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
 int a = 2;
 fo.write(a);
 fo.close();
```

Whenever I run this program and open the "even.txt" file, all I'm able to see is a hash symbol in the file. This doesn't happen when I work with a string.

```
 File f = new File("even.txt");
 FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
 String s = "2";
 byte b[] = s.getBytes();
 fo.write(b);
 fo.close();
```

I don't understand why this happens.

Comment: `fo.write(2)` isn't actually writing the number 2 but a byte instead. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#write-int-

Comment: Hashtags are just a social media feature. Saying you can see a hashtag makes no sense in this context. It's like saying "I can see a tweet". What are you seeing? A hash symbol (`#`)? or something else?

Comment: Yes a hash symbol

Comment: If you want to write human-readable text to a file, you should be using a `Writer`, not an `OutputStream`.

Comment: I would think most people on here would know that when people write "hashtag" it's synonymous with hash symbol and pound sign even. While I agree it's not the exact right name of the symbol, it does still make sense and can extrapolate what is meant.

Comment: @Ascalonian I could certainly guess that the OP might mean a hash symbol, but it was also possible that they meant some other symbol they didn't know the name of, or even 
 (something like) a hash code, which is why I asked them to confirm what they meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have to understand is

```
int a = 2;
fo.write(a); //This line write the byte 0x02 to the inputstream because that is the binary representation of the digit 2

String s = "2";
byte b[] = s.getBytes();
fo.write(b); //This one write 0x32 to the inputstream because that is the ascii respresentation of the character "2" which is return by getBytes() from the string class
```

you can check the difference between the two file the code generate in an hex editor

Answer (score 3):

You have to write String. You can try one of:

```
wr.write("222");
wr.write(new Integer(222).toString());
wr.write( String.valueOf(222) );
```

it's because the method fo.write(int) doesn't actually write the int itself, it writes the character represented by the int in the encoding specified (utf-8 if not specified).